# How to view dynamically generated Pulp Equations

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pulp

I have formulated a LP with dynamically generated constraints and equations. How can I view the whole equation and constraints so generated? Looked in documentation found no reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many modeling systems provide surprisingly little help in terms of debugging tools. In those cases you may have to rely on writing an LP file (in PuLP: method `writeLP`).